# How to query from Firebase storage inside a for loop?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to loop through an `Arraylist` of personal objects I called `CardModel`. And for each `cardModel` I want to go to Firebase Storage and grab me the corresponding image for that `cardModel` object. The problem is, I finish the for loop before the query from Firebase storage, so it adds the images incorrectly. I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem.

```
        private int q = 1;
        for(CardModel cardModel : localCardArray)
        {
            imageStorage = storageRef.child("reference to firebase storage");
            imageStorage.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes)
                {
                    localByteArray.add(bytes);

                   //Once you're at the end of the arraylist, run next method
                    if(q++ == localCardArray.size())
                    {
                        setAdapter();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    Log.d("testingImageInMain", "failure!");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: There's a lot of details missing here.  What's `localByteArray`, that only appears once in your code?  What does `setAdapter()` do?  What is it doing incorrectly, and what is the expected correct behavior?

Comment: You basically want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621260/asynchronous-multiple-photos-upload-with-firebase (but in reverse). Create multiple `tasks` then `waitAll` to download them.